# What is the minimum target CPU architecture for the various versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

What is the minimum target processor architecture (indicated with `_M_IX86` predefined macros) supported by every version of Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012?

For example,  MSVS 2012 supports only Pentium Pro and higher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic switch for this was `/G`. Your available options differed for different versions of the compiler (with newer versions dropping older options, albeit continuing to accept them for compatibility reasons). Here's what you got:

- `/G3` built code that was optimized for 386 processors (`_M_IX86` was set to 300)
- `/G4` for the 486 processor (`_M_IX86` was set to 400)
- `/G5` built code that was optimized for the Pentium (`_M_IX86` was set to 500)
- `/G6` built code that was optimized for the Pentium Pro, II, and III (`_M_IX86` was set to 600)
- `/G7` built code that was optimized for the Pentium 4 or AMD Athlon (`_M_IX86` was set to 700)
- `/GB` specified either "blend" mode or the lowest common denominator that was reasonable when that version of the compiler was released. This was the default option if no other was specified.

And of course, it bears explicit mention that setting this option to optimize for a *newer* processor architecture did not prevent your code from running on an older processor architecture. It just wasn't *optimized* for that architecture and might run more slowly.

However, if you look up this compiler option in [a current version of the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h66s5s0e.aspx), you'll see no mention of any of this. All you see is something about Itanium processors (which we'll put aside). That's because [the compiler shipping with VC++ 2005 dropped the `/G3`–`/G7` compiler options altogether](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4bcz65t.aspx):

> [The] `/G3`, `/G4`, `/G5`, `/G6`, `/G7`, and `/GB` compiler options have been removed. The compiler now uses a "blended model" that attempts to create the best output file for all architectures.

So, although many of us remember it well from VC++ 6, this code generation setting was a historical curiosity only even as far back as VC++ 2008. Therefore I'm not sure where you get the impression that VS 2012 supports only the Pentium Pro. I can't find mention of that anywhere in the official documentation or elsewhere online. The limiting factor for version 2012 of the compiler is not the processor architecture but the OS version. If you've patched the compiler, libraries, and all the other accoutrements to support targeting Windows XP, then you will be able to run your application on an original Pentium-233, onto which you've masochistically shoe-horned Windows XP.

The purpose of the `_M_IX86` macro is really just an indicator that you're targeting the Intel IA-32 processor family—more commonly known as good old 32-bit x86—in contrast to one of the other supported target architectures, like `_M_AMD64` for 64-bit x86. You should just treat it as a defined/undefined value now.

Yes, the old table of values for `_M_IX86` still appears in [the latest version of the preprocessor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx), but it is utterly obsolete. You'll note that other obsolete symbols appear there as well, such as `_M_PPC`: what was the last version of MSVC++ that shipped with a PowerPC compiler? 4.2?

---

But that is only part of the story. There are still other compiler options that govern code generation with respect to target architectures.

For example, the `/arch` switch. From [the latest version of the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx), you have the following options:

- `/arch:IA32` which essentially sets the lowest common denominator, using x87 for floating point
- `/arch:SSE` which turns on SSE instructions
- `/arch:SSE2` which turns on SSE2 instructions (and is the *default* for x86)
- `/arch:AVX` which turns on Intel Advanced Vector Extensions
- `/arch:AVX2` which turns on Intel Advanced Vector Extensions 2

  If you read the Remarks section, you'll also see that these options can imply more than just the specified instruction set. For example, since all processors that support SSE instructions also support the `CMOV` instruction, the `CMOV` instruction will be generated when `/arch:SSE` or higher is specified. The `CMOV` instruction has nothing to do with SSE; in fact, SSE was introduced with the Pentium III while `CMOV` was introduced way back with the Pentium Pro. But it's guaranteed to be supported on any architectures that support SSE.

The other relevant option is controlled by the `/favor` switch. This was new starting with VC++ 2008, and was presumably the replacement for the old `/G3`–`/G7` options. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173505.aspx) says:

- `/favor:blend` is the default and produces code with no unique optimizations
- `/favor:INTEL64` generates code specific for Intel's implementation of x86-64
- `/favor:AMD64` generates code specific for AMD's implementation of x86-64
- `/favor:ATOM` generates code specific for Intel's Atom processor

Comment: There is the `/GL` optimization which does global optimizations across modules (it's enabled by default).  I had to disable it in order to resemble the dissembled 32-bit assembly (64-bit is broken).

Comment: I build my project witch /arch:IA32, but MSVS2012 still generate code with CMOVX commands(on strncmp() function). How can I prevent this?

Comment: @user Are you targeting x86-64 (64-bit)? If so, then yes, you will naturally get CMOVX instructions—because *all* 64-bit processors are *guaranteed* to support conditional moves. Make sure that the target architecture is "x86". (You will also need `/arch:IA32`, though, because the default starting with Visual Studio 2012 is to assume SSE2 support.)

Comment: Platform set to win32

Comment: @user Okay, yeah I repro that on VS 2012 & 2013. The problem is that an optimized version of `strncmp` (and several other functions) is provided for the x86 processor, and those optimized functions are hand-written using inline assembly. Check in your Visual Studio folder, under Program Files, at the following path: `..\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\intel\strncmp.asm`. None of the obvious compiler options solve this problem, including disabling intrinsic functions. Not sure what to tell you. Looks like the optimized functions only support i686 and higher.

Comment: I don't think this is documented anywhere. Probably because it is not a compiler problem, but a standard library implementation issue. If open the implementation of `strncmp` bundled with the compiler, the one written in pure C and available at `..\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\strncmp.c`, copy the function into your project file, and compile it, you'll see that no `CMOVxx` instructions are generated. That proves it's not the compiler doing it, but that it is simply being forced by inline assembly in the optimized implementation. It also suggests a workaround, albeit a dirty one.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I did just that.